# Enable external VGA output on a laptop with a broken screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, external-monitor

I have a laptop (Packard bell with Nvidia graphics) with broken screen.

How do I enable the vga external output for an external monitor? (I suppose that i have to change the x configurations?)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`xrandr --output VGA1 --auto`

Best results if you `ssh` into the laptop and verify the parameters with `xrandr`.